# Datastax Devcenter failing to create connection

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

In my windows 10 I have installed Datastax Devcenter, it is failing to create connection and throwing below error.

```
The specified host(s) could not be reached.
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.70.13:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.70.13:9042] Cannot connect))
[/192.168.70.13:9042] Cannot connect
```

I need a solution to fix this issue.

Comment: do you have access to this machine, port 9042 is reachable?

Comment: Yes port 9042 is reachable

Comment: What version of DSE?

Comment: DevCenter Version is 1.5.0

Comment: No, version of DSE to which you trying to connect... You can find it by connecting via cqlsh, or checking package version on that machine